# Testing Node Express API routes via remote http-client

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I've following situation: node with express running on my local machine and a remote linux-box within the private adress space of my network.

Here's the compact index.js example using nodejs & express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('RESTful Demo..');
});

app.get('/api/read', (req,res) => {
    console.log('test 123..');
    res.send([1, 2, 3]);
});

// Array to simulate some db-entries
const jsObject = [
    { pk: 1, value: 'data1'},
    { pk: 2, value: 'data2'},
    { pk: 3, value: 'data3'}
];

app.get('/api/read/:pk', (req,res) => {
    var pk = req.params.pk;
    console.log(pk);
    let myMatchedObject = jsObject.find(c => c.pk === parseInt(req.params.pk));
    if (!myMatchedObject) res.status(404).send('The given Primaray Key was not found..'); // 404
    res.send(myMatchedObject);
});

// PORT envar
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Listening-process
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on Port ${port}..`));
```

Ive sucessfully tried it via browser locally and from remote, but I've tried curl from a remote Linux-Box within my private adress space of my network but i couldn't invoke the API.

I've tried (with enabling for proxy-tunnels) *curl -o test.txt -p http://192.168.1.152:3000/api/read* with no success..

Then i tried some successful tests on jsonplaceholder API with *curl  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users*

With that in mind, i cloned the repo and tried it on my local machine - again with no response from curl.

What fundamental thought am I missing?

Comment: Problem solved - network restrictions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to our network restrictions i wasn't able to curl inside our private adress space..